# How to read the contents of a file inside an epub using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, epub3

I need to read, inside a page of an epub3 book, the contents of one of the file of that same epub, being some data to process with a javascript function.
Unfortunately, Javascript prevents from loading local files for security reasons. (e.g the File API only allows loading uploaded user files).

But for me in the context of an epub3, it makes sense and I didn't find any information in the IDPF EPUB3 documentation related to this topic.

Any idea ?

OK. Let's clarify:

I have an epub3 with the following structure:

```
<root>
    META-INF
        ...
    OEBPS
        pages
            page.xhtml
        data
            data.xml
```

In page.xhtml, I want to write in Javascript something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//pseudo code
var indata = readAsText("../data/data.xml"); // how to write that ???
var outdata = myfunction(indata);
</script>
```

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/

Comment: so don't read it as a `file:///`, just run a localhost server (with a daemon like apache, or using a one-line call using python, or php, or using a nodejs util like `http-server` or `live-server`, or any other of the million ways to do that) and access it over `http://`

Comment: Don't remember that the ePub3 is meant to be read in an ebook reader. Running a localhost server is not a solution..

Comment: Running a server is the solution to loading local files. Why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: An ebook epub3 is self-contained. It cannot rely on any external software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for ages, and realized that it had never been answered:
So answering to my own question ;-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Load the file using HTTP GET */
    $.get( "../data/data.xml", function( indata ) {
    var outdata = myfunction(indata);
    }, 'text');
</script>
```